# How manage elements class name by any expression in jquery in mvc4 application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html-lists

There are `<li>` elements that one of them has `class="current"`. I want to decide which of `<li>` is current. Here is view:

```
@{
     int k = 10;  //this will change in every request
}

<ul class="car">
     @foreach (var item in modelCount)
     {
       <li 
           @{if (item.Id == k) { <text>class="current"</text>} }>
           <a href="#">@item.Name </a>
       </li>
     }
</ul>
```

This works, but the first `<li>` is always current by default. When first element is current by my expression, everything is ok, but otherwise, `<ul>` has 2 current `<li>`.
How can I solve this problem with jquery function?

**Edit:**

**I need:**

**If `<li>` elements have 2 current classes, to remove the first of them.**

Comment: don't know if you copy pasted your code but you forgot the `>` for the first `li` element

Comment: no, it is at end of @{if()}  expression.

Comment: Yup you are completely right my mistake there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function removeDuplicateCurrentClass(){

    var currentListElements = [];

    $('ul.car li').each(function(){

         if($(this).hasClass('current'))
             currentListElements.push(this);
    });

    if(currentListElements.length > 1)
         $(currentListElements[0]).removeClass('current');
    //if more than one current class exist: remove the first one        

}

$(function(){

    removeDuplicateCurrentClass();

    //or simply

    if($('ul.car li.current').length > 1)
        $('ul.car li.current:first').removeClass('current');

});
```

Comment: this part of your code gives syntax error;

 $(ul.tour li).each(function(){
            if($(this).hasClass('current'))
                currentListElements.push($(this));
        });
  I cannot find error

Comment: we had forget ' symbol. I added it. But still there is 2 current <li> in the page

Comment: this does not remove first class when <ul> have 2 current classes

Comment: Didn't know that you wanted it removed from the DOM, but I'll update the code